# limit of $L^1$ functions to power $p \to 0^+$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f \in L^1$ is non-vanishing on $[0,1]$, show that $\lim_{p \to 0^+} \int \lvert f \rvert^p = 1$.

It is an assignment question.

My intuition tells me that $\lvert f \rvert^p$ will converge to $f = 1$ on $[0,1]$, when $p \to 0^+$.

Or another way to think is that I can construct $E_n = \{x \in [0,1]: \lvert \lvert f\rvert^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1 \rvert < \epsilon\}$ this sequence is decreasing, and I should prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}m(E_n) = 0$, so it converge almost everywhere to $f = 1$. Then I should be able to conclude that the integral is equal to 1. But it still is not equivalent to that $\lim_{p \to 0^+} \int \lvert f \rvert^p = 1$. It is a little messy and I hope someone can give me some help.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the [Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). Find a suitable function $g$ (which you can get by modifying $f$ a little bit) that is integrable with $|g| \geq |f|^p$ for all $p \leq 1$. The theorem then allows you to move the limit inside the integral. As you observed, $|f|^p$ converges pointwise to 1, so you obtain the desired result.